# Fast Screen Transfer

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, video, screen

What is the fastest way in C++ to share screens between computers, like in Skype or Google Plus? Currently I'm taking a screenshot, convert it to low-quality JPG with GDI+ and then send it too a remote computer, but although it works, it is not very fast (7 FPS via localhost).

Answer (score 3):

I can't comment :(
But some things to think about.

1. *Which* operation(s) take the most time? I suspect this would be the capture due to the localhost xmission - but it really could be anything. Benchmark.
2. Does the sender "block" the next frame generation while waiting on the recipient display? If this is so then it might add in an implict bottleneck. The sender probably wants to keep sending frames unless the recipient requests a throttle.
3. If bandwidth is an issue, what about only sending partial or delta frames? Even though localhost shouldn't be a bandwidth issue, I am fairly certain that this is done in more advanced clients.
4. Consider looking at some [open source] VNC clients for how they work. It's not necessarily the same as "Skype", but it shound provide insight for a screen sharing program.